# What is causing my Javascript game to behave differently on other computers?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

So I was creating a simple game on my computer that spawns circles randomly and you have to dodge them so I can learn a bit of javascript. On my computer the enemies spawn consistently over time but on my laptop, it like waits for 20 enemies to spawn and then they all start to move together. I am not sure why this is happening and how to avoid things like this. I am using the same version of Google Chrome on both machines. I believe the offending code has to do with my spawn enemies function. I pick a random number between 0-3 so that I can choose which edge to spawn the enemy in and then I use the time to randomly generate the enemies at different intervals.

The rest of my code can be found here too: http://jsfiddle.net/54dos0e9/

Also if anyone has any suggestions on how to test for these kinds of problems without having to use different machines I would like to know what would be best. 
Thanks for your time.

```
function renderEnemies(time) {
  var randomStartX = 0;
  var randomStartY = 0;

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

  switch (rand) {
    case 0:
      randomStartX = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width);
      randomStartY = 0;
      break;
    case 1:
      randomStartX = 0;
      randomStartY = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.height);
      break;

    case 2:
      randomStartX = c.width;
      randomStartY = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.height);
      break;

    case 3:
      randomStartX = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width);
      randomStartY = c.height;
      break;
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (Math.round(time) % difficulty.amount == 0) {
    //console.log("WIDTH HEIGHT " + c.height);
    //console.log("RAND IS "+ rand);
    //console.log("X is " + randomStartX);
    //console.log("Y is " + randomStartY);
    //console.log("CANVAS" + c.width);

    enemies.push({
      x: randomStartX,
      y: randomStartY,
      edge: rand,
      tempX: randomStartX,
      tempY: randomStartY
    });
    //console.log(enemies.length);
  }

  //To prevent the enemy list from growing too large, we remove from the beginning to free up memory
  if (enemies.length == 50) {
    enemies.splice(0, 25);
  }

  enemies.forEach(function(p) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    hitbox(p);
  });
  //console.log(enemies.length);
  /////////////////////////////////
}
```

Edit: Said this in a comment but I realized that it has to do with the if statement dealing with rounding my time variable. For some reason on my laptop, it never finds a divisible number for a few seconds then all of a sudden it finds like 10 of them at once. I am not sure why this is happening though, going to have to mess around with the values and figure out a better time interval.

Comment: Rather than blaming different 'computers', it's probably more related to the browser version, the js engine used. I'm glaring at the `forEach` with a suspicion it's not being supported by some of them.

Comment: @LukStorms The problem as I mentioned is that I am using the same exact version of Google Chrome on both computers (Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)) so I figured maybe it was something more than that. I realized that it has to do with the if statement dealing with rounding my time variable. For some reason on my laptop, it never finds a divisible number for a few seconds then all of a sudden it finds like 10 of them at once. Edit: Maybe it's the version of java installed on the machine? It might sound dumb but I feel like that could affect it

Comment: Could the use of the modulus `%` on the rounded time be related?  Seems kinda random to me.

Comment: @LukStorms, yea it definitely is. I figured if I decrease the % difficulty from like 50 to 20, then it would have more times to spawn the enemy since for example, times 20,40,60,80,100 would spawn more enemies divisible by 20 than just 50, 100 divisible by 50. Or at least that was my logic but for some reason on my laptop it wildly differs in spawn times. It almost seems predictable too. Like instead of randomly spawning every second or two, it just halts for about 10 seconds and then all of a sudden it spawns 15 of them at a time every time. I'm just going to avoid using this logic